running detox tests in CI with Github Actions for android
i am trying to integrate detox tests in github actions for Android, getting this error while i try to run tests.

detox[19006] i Vacation Mode Detox Test Cases: login with valid username and password
detox[19006] i Unable to get output buffers (err=-38)
Encoder failed (err=-38)
detox[19006] i ""/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "ps | grep "com.test.testapp$""" failed with error = ChildProcessError: Command failed: "/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "ps | grep "com.test.testapp$""
"/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-5554 shell "ps | grep \"com\.test\.testapp$\"" (exited with error code 1) (code=1), stdout and stderr:
detox[19006] i
detox[19006] i

i am able to download, assign and run emulator, but some how its getting failed at intial onboarding page.
tests are executed but all tests fail with above error.
i am able to run ios tests successfully in github actions.
Below is my github actions yaml file code for downloading and running android emulator
            - name: Download Android Emulator Image
              run: |
                  echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --install $PACKAGE
                  echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name Pixel_5 --device "pixel_5" --package $PACKAGE --sdcard 1024M
                  # adb start-server
                  $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -list-avds
                  $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager list device
                  $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager list avd
              env:
                  PACKAGE: 'system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86'

            - name: Change Android Emulator settings
              run: |
                  echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sysctl -p
                  mkdir -p /root/.android && touch /root/.android/repositories.cfg
                  echo "vm.heapSize=1024M" >> $AVD_PATH/config.ini
                  echo "hw.ramSize=2048M" >> $AVD_PATH/config.ini
                  echo "disk.dataPartition.size=2048m" >> $AVD_PATH/config.ini
                  grep "size" $AVD_PATH/config.ini
              env:
                  AVD_NAME: Pixel_5
                  AVD_PATH: /Users/runner/.android/avd/Pixel_5.avd

            - name: Android Emulator
              timeout-minutes: 10
              continue-on-error: true
              run: |
                  echo "Starting emulator"
                  nohup $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-snapshot -no-window -gpu swiftshader_indirect @Pixel_5 &
                  nohup $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-snapshot -no-window -partition-size 2048 @Pixel_5 &
                  $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r') ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
                  $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices
                  echo "Emulator started"

so ideally it should run all tests and provide me with test results, but currently all tests are failing irrespective of its execution status because of emulator issue.
